# Why is my rspec test doubling my objects?

Tags: ruby, rspec2

This is one of those cases where my code is working but my test is failing and I need to know what I am doing wrong?

I have a Project class with an `all` method that just spits out instances of this class:

```
class Project

    @@all_projects = []

    def initialize(options)
      @@all_projects << self
    end

    def self.all
    @@all_projects
  end
end
```

Now `Project.all` works just fine but the spec I am writing doesn't.

```
context "manipulating projects" do
    before do
        options1 = {
            name: 'Building house'
        }

        options2 = {
            name: 'Getting a loan from the Bank'
        }

        @project1 = Project.new(options1)
        @project2 = Project.new(options2)
    end
        it "can print all projects" do
      Project.all.should eq([@project1, @project2])
    end
```

The failure message I get is:

```
Project manipulating projects can print all projects
     Failure/Error: Project.all.should eq([@project1, @project2])

       expected: [Building house, Getting a loan from the Bank]
            got: [Building house, Building house, Building house, Getting a loan from the Bank, Building house, Getting a loan from the Bank]
```

Here is the full spec in a gist: https://gist.github.com/4535863

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Better formatting of the code (especially in the gist) would help my head hurt less from reading it.

Comment: Is this the *only* spec? If not, same problem as before.

Comment: fixed it to a certain extent - I don't know why indents are not working - sorry

Comment: set your tab indents to use spaces.

Comment: @DaveNewTon Yes - this is the same problem and there are other specs too. You see I had no clue about using after blocks.

Comment: @AmitErandole it's not really an issue of using `after` blocks, it's an issue of clearing your class variable. You could to it in a `before` or `after` block, or in each spec if you wanted to, just a matter of how you want to organize your test code and what you're actually testing.

Comment: @AmitErandole It's because the class is loaded and used across all the specs--the Ruby VM doesn't close and open again, it's all running in the same environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is doubling the results because it runs the `before` block for *each* test, where the class attribute is modified (when two new projects are initialized), and (according to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/4535863)) the test you're referring to is the second one.

To avoid the problem you'll need to reset `@@all_projects` in an after block:

```
after do
  Project.class_variable_set :@@all_projects, []
end
```

See also: [How can I clear class variables between rspec tests in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274865/how-can-i-clear-class-variables-between-rspec-tests-in-ruby)

(Thanks to @[iain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335847/iain) for the suggestion to move the reset code to an `after` block rather than a `before` block.)

Comment: …or an `after` block. Those instance variables (`@projectX`) would be better off defined using `let` too.

Comment: @iain could you please show me how the after and let blocks would look like

Comment: @iain with a `let` block (no bang), the first test (testing the number of projects) would fail as-is. You'd have to use `let!`, which would basically do the same thing as a `before` block.

Comment: @shioyama that's because the specs are designed badly. Wherever I see an instance variable set in a `before` block I know there's a spec missing things or affecting other parts of the spec. A `let!` isn't needed, see my answer.

Comment: @shioyama I should add, I'm not arguing with you, I seem argumentative there :) Just making my point.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use `before` blocks to set stinky instance variables.

```
describe Project do
  let(:options1){ 
    {
      name: 'Building house',
      priority: 2,
      tasks: []
    }
  }
  let(:options2) {
    {
      name: 'Getting a loan from the Bank',
      priority: 3,
      tasks: []
    }
  }
  let(:project1) { Project.new(options1) }
  let(:project2) { Project.new(options2) }

  context "while starting up" do

    subject { Project.new options1 }
    its(:name) { should include('Building house') }

    its(:tasks) { should be_empty }
  end

  context "manipulating projects" do
    before :all do
      Project.all.clear
    end

    subject { Project.all }
    its(:count) { should be > 0 }

    it { should eq [project1, project2] }

  end

end
```

Comment: Oh so that's how you use `let`. I am gonna try this out. Thanks @iain.  But can you tell me why exactly is it better to avoid instance variables in tests? For decoupling?

Comment: For the same reason global variables are avoided - the less tightly scoped your state, the more likely something will change when it shouldn't. Using `let` protects examples from changing state that affects other examples better than instance variables do, and I think it helps structure specs with better clarity by making `before` and `after` blocks used for side effects and `let` for variables you'll need.